# Retrofit 2 - Elegant way of adding headers in the api level

Tags: java, header, annotations, retrofit, retrofit2

My Retrofit 2 (`2.0.2` currently) client needs to add custom headers to requests.

I'm using an `Interceptor` to add these headers to all requests:

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .addHeader("CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME_1", "CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE_1")
                .addHeader("CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME_2", "CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE_2")
                ...
                .addHeader("CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME_N", "CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE_N")
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});


Retrofit retrofitClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(httpClient)
        .build();
```

Some headers I always want to add, but some headers I only need to add based on requirements of that specific endpoint, for example whether the user needs to be authenticated or not.

I'd like to have the ability to control that at the api level, for example using an annotation, something like:

```
public interface MyApi {
    @NO_AUTH
    @POST("register")
    Call<RegisterResponse> register(@Body RegisterRequest data);

    @GET("user/{userId}")
    Call<GetUserResponse> getUser(@Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

When sending a request to `register` there's no need to add the authentication token, but requests who lack the `@NO_AUTH` annotation will have the token header.

From what I understand Retrofit 2 doesn't support custom annotations, and while I found this workaround for [Custom Annotations with Retrofit 2](https://medium.com/@andretietz/custom-annotations-with-retrofit-2-8701ca7ce102#.79dg4wb8v), it's seems a bit too much.

I'd like to avoid the need to pass these headers per request, like:

```
public interface MyApi {
    @POST("register")
    Call<RegisterResponse> register(@Body RegisterRequest data);

    @GET("user/{userId}")
    Call<GetUserResponse> getUser(@Header("AuthToken") String token, @Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

It just feels redundant to do it every time I call the method instead of doing it in the interceptor (since I have access to the header values statically).
I just somehow need to know in my `Interceptor.intercept` implementation whether or not this specific request should have a specific header(s).

Any idea how I can make this work?
I prefer a generic solution and not just for the auth token case, but a specific solution is welcome as well. 
Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I came up with a very simple and elegant (in my opinion) solution to my problem, and probably for other scenarios.

I use the `Headers` annotation to pass my custom annotations, and since OkHttp requires that they follow the `Name: Value` format, I decided that my format will be: `@: ANNOTATION_NAME`.

So basically:

```
public interface MyApi {
    @POST("register")
    @HEADERS("@: NoAuth")
    Call<RegisterResponse> register(@Body RegisterRequest data);

    @GET("user/{userId}")
    Call<GetUserResponse> getUser(@Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

Then I can intercept the request, check whether I have an annotation with name `@`. If so, I get the value and remove the header from the request.
This works well even if you want to have more than one "custom annotation":

```
@HEADERS({
    "@: NoAuth",
    "@: LogResponseCode"
})
```

Here's how to extract all of these "custom annotations" and remove them from the request:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();

        List<String> customAnnotations = request.headers().values("@");

        // do something with the "custom annotations"

        request = request.newBuilder().removeHeader("@").build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this mean you are using new ```OkHttpClient``` for every request ?

Comment: @panduka No. That was just for the example, you can have one client.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution actually, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @NitzanTomer well crafted solution. it is working well but i was wondering why the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` still shows `@: NoAuth` in the header. is it because it is intercepted before being removed ?

Comment: @Poorya Maybe you added the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` before this interceptor? If that's the case then the logging happens before the headers were removed by this interceptor.

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes, that should be the case.

Comment: @Poorya Can you add the `HttpLoggingInterceptor` after this one or is that a problem?

Comment: This worked for me, but had to set the interceptor with `OkHttpClient.Builder#addInterceptor()` and not `OkHttpClient.Builder#addNetworkInterceptor()`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can do that by creating different Retrofit object factory method like this.

```
public class RestClient {
    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static <S> S createServiceWithAuth(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                final Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME_1", "CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE_1")
                        .addHeader("CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME_2", "CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE_2")
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        };
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

if you want to call api without header auth, you can just call createService method:

```
YourApi api = RestClient.createService(YourApi.class);
```

And use createServiceWithAuth method if you want to call api with authentication:

```
YourApiWithAuth api = RestClient.createServiceWithAuth(YourApiWithAuth.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution but it requires me to group together the endpoints in different classes based on whether or not the requests need to be authenticated, and that's not very convenient.

Comment: Good luck with instantiating resource-expensive Retrofit every time you need it.

Comment: That's the correct solution. Authenticated and unauthenticated requests should be separated as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like in [this article](https://blog.christophe-henry.dev/2020/02/23/tweak-your-retrofit-behavior-with-annotations.html)

I have added a small bonus extension to shorten everything

```kotlin
fun Request.isAnnotationPresent(annotation: Class<out Annotation>) =
    tag(Invocation::class.java)?.method()?.isAnnotationPresent(annotation) ?: false

private class CustomInterceptor(private val account: Account): Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {chain.request().tag(Invocation::class.java)?.method()
        if(chain.request().isAnnotationPresent(CustomAnnotation)) {
            // Do your stuff
        }
        return chain.proceed(chain.request())
    }
}
```