# How can i post data with utf8 from Android to server

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I want POST data from android to server, my server language is PHP.
When POST data, this data save with strange characters , such as this : `ÙˆØ¨ ØªÛŒØ­ÛŒ` . this data is utf8 characters and this data is not OK!. For requests i use `Retrofit2`

**My POST request is :**

```
private void sendComment(String cmPostID, String name, String email, String content) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        Retrofit_ApiInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);

        comment = new Comment();
        comment.setComment_post_ID(cmPostID);
        comment.setComment_author(name);
        comment.setComment_author_email(email);
        comment.setComment_content(content);

        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.COMMENT);
        request.setComment(comment);

        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.cmOperation(request);
        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                if (resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                    sendLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    TastyToast.makeText(context, StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(resp.getMessage()), TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,
                            TastyToast.SUCCESS);
                    closeCommentDialog();
                } else {
                    sendCommentImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sendLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    TastyToast.makeText(context, StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(resp.getMessage()), TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,
                            TastyToast.ERROR);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                sendLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                sendCommentImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TastyToast.makeText(context, "Faild, send Again please", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
            }
        });
}
```

How can i fix this problem, and send data with UTF8 ?

Comment: can you post up the logs? Would be helpful if the request header and payload is available.

Comment: @SamuelKok, how can i set header to my request? can you help me my friend? please

Comment: you can add header to your request as in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757520/retrofit-2-elegant-way-of-adding-headers-in-the-api-level). What's the payload you're sending out though, I can't tell if the server is reading it wrongly or your android app is encoding it wrongly.

Comment: @SamuelKok, What should I write in Header? can you help me?

Comment: I can't advise on that since I've no clue what the problem is. Unless you've posted up the logs, request header and payload of the retrofit request.

Comment: @SamuelKok, if i send request logs (from android monitor tab), can you help me my friend?